# React - page flickering on new component entering DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, styled-components, intersection-observer

We have been trying to display component on the bottom of the page (sticky action bar), if certain components are not in view (using intersection observer).
Suddenly, the page started flickering.

This is our onScreen hook:

```
   const useOnScreen = (options, targetRef) => {
    const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false)    

    const callbackFunction = (entries) => {
        const [entry] = entries
        setIsVisible(entry.isIntersecting)
    }

    const optionsMemo = useMemo(() => {
        return options
    }, [options])

    useEffect(() => {
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callbackFunction, optionsMemo)
        const currentTarget = targetRef.current

        if (currentTarget) observer.observe(currentTarget)

        return () => {
            if (currentTarget) observer.unobserve(currentTarget)
        }
    }, [targetRef, optionsMemo])

    return isVisible
}
```

And we're using it like following in components:

```
const isVisible = useOnScreen({root: null, rootMargin: '0px', threshold: 0}, targetRef)
```

And since we need it in parent component, to conditionally render another one, we're saving it to global Recoil state:

```
 // Setting isHeroVisible state to global state
    useEffect(() => {
        setIsHeroVisible(isVisible)
    }, [isVisible])
```

This is how it's used on the main page:

```
 const isOpenModal = useRecoilValue(notifyMeAtom)
 const isHeroVisible = useRecoilValue(isHeroVisibleAtom)
 const isFooterVisible = useRecoilValue(isFooterVisibleAtom)

    // StickyCTA should be visible only if none of refs are on screen
    const shouldDisplayCTA = !isHeroVisible && !isFooterVisible && !isOpenModal

    return shouldDisplayCTA && <StickyCTA />
```

We debugged the app and thought the whole page was re-rendering, but it wasn't (there are no any network or other changes). What we did notice were the fonts being re-fetched when component appeared, as can be seen on screenshot below:

[image]

Also another thing we noticed is that when component enters the DOM, some of the classnames are being updated (at the moment when state changes in useOnScreen hook).
We are using styled components.

Comment: I would first try checking the value of `shouldDisplayCTA` without rendering your `<StickyCTA />` component. Does that return true/false as expected?

Comment: @AlexGourlay yes, it's rendering in correct moments

Comment: Does the flickering occur, when not rendering the `<StickyCTA />` component?

Comment: @AlexGourlay when we're not rendering the component and also comment out all useOnScreen hooks, no, the flickering is not occurring.

Comment: One possible explanation is that when you render your `<StickyCTA />` component, you cause a change in your html layout, so that your header/footer/modal actually come back in or out of view. Which, in turn, causes your `<StickyCTA />` to stop rendering, which moves the header/foorer/modal out of view etc. etc.  Creating an infinite loop of on/off, which would appear as flickering. I have encountered such a problem before.

Comment: @AlexGourlay It's not infinite loop, it happens only on appearing and disappearing of StickyCTA. Do you have some suggestion maybe on which steps we should take?
Also, it doesn't happen on production build, it works just fine there.

Answer (score -1):

you are probably using `local` to import the .woff2 fonts.
example:

```css
@Font {
      font family: 'K2D';
      font style: normal;
      font display: swap;
      src: local('K2D Bold'), local('K2D-Bold'),
          url('/fonts/K2D-Bold.woff2') format('woff2');
    }
```

use without the 'location', just pass the url

```css
@Font {
     font family: 'K2D';
      font style: normal;
      font display: swap;
     src: url('/fonts/K2D-Bold.woff2') format('woff2');
    }
```